# how to show perticular category posts in custome page

Tags: custom-post-types, categories

i know how to define custom post template vai plugins very easily but i want without plugins how can i define custom post template for particular category post.

say like i have one category "members" under this category have ten post. so i want when show those member post that time show custom template.

see bellow code from twentytwelve theme category.php file

```
<?php
            /* Start the Loop */
            while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

                /* Include the post format-specific template for the content. If you want to
                 * this in a child theme then include a file called called content-___.php
                 * (where ___ is the post format) and that will be used instead.
                 */
                get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );

            endwhile;

            twentytwelve_content_nav( 'nav-below' );
            ?>

        <?php else : ?>
            <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'none' ); ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

see in above code say `get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );` and see `get_template_part( 'content', 'none' )` now i want when "members" category post will open it will one custom page.. like `content-members.php` file, so i think code will be like that `get_template_part( 'content', 'members' )`

so how can define in category page members category post will open content-members.php file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `is_category` to check if the category is "members" and then load the appropriate template.

In `get_template_part()` use the template name for the second parameter instead of `get_post_format()`.

In this example your template should be named "content-members.php."

```
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

    if ( is_category( 'members' ) ) {

         get_template_part( 'content', 'members' );

    } else {

        get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );

    }

endwhile;
```

Comment: thanks you so much @epilektric  ... and how can i define single post too.. mean which members category post show in custome page. like single-members.php page

Comment: i already tried bellow code in single.php file but not work

  

    <?php
        if ( is_category( 'members' ) ) {
    
             get_template_part( 'content', 'members' );
    
        } else {
    
            get_template_part( 'content', 'common' );
    
        }
     ?>


i think category not tigger here.

Comment: @pagol If my answer worked for you I'd appreciate the up vote. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use in_category to check if the category is "members" and then load the appropriate template.

In get_template_part() use the template name for the second parameter instead of get_post_format().

In this example your template should be named "content-members.php."

```
while ( have_posts() ) : 
    the_post();

    if ( in_category( 'members' ) ) {
         get_template_part( 'content', 'members' );
    } else {
        get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );
    }
endwhile;
```

I change `is_category( 'members' )` to  `in_category( 'members' )`

Comment: This does something slightly different, though: is_category('members') means 'are we showing the members archive page' whereas in_category() means 'is this post in the members category'.